# How to write two separate for loops on the same line and get full output from both in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm new to Python, so there are some things I can't figure out, and I'm asking you to guide me. As a very simple example, we have two short lists that we want to show their output completely using a for loop, but unfortunately, it seems that there is no solution for this issue in Python.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
list2 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

I tracked this issue using zip. But in the output of one of the lists, which was longer than the other, its values are not displayed completely.

```
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    print(l1, l2)
```

Output:

```
1 20
2 21
3 22
4 23
5 24
6 25
7 26
8 27
```

While we want the final output to be as follows:

```
1 20
2 21
3 22
4 23
5 24
6 25
7 26
8 27
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Of course, this solution is not intended to be achieved with zip, it is only given as an example.

Can you give a solution for this type of output? Or is there a way for this type of output or is what we consider as an output completely wrong and there is no such thing?

Thank you for guiding me in this matter. Thank you in advance for the additional information. Good luck.

Comment: Traditionally one uses a `set` in that context, e.g. `assert 3 == len(set([7, 8, 8, 9]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `zip_longest`, which can handle the case, if it gets one list longer than other one :

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
list2 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]

for l1, l2 in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=""):
    print(l1, l2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. Always be successful.